# Parsing nested json file with decoder

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I am having trouble parsing this json file

```
{"window":60,"version":200,"timestamp":1582886130,"body":{"totals":{"count":1,"offset":0},"audio_clips":[{"id":7515224,"title":"The West Ham Way Podcast - We`re back!","description":"This is a message from Dave to confirm that the boys are back....\nThe show will be recorded EVERY Wednesday and published on the same night. Please subscribe to this Podcast on your preferred platform and get the West Ham Way back to where they were before it was taken away from them.\nAs always, thanks for your support. COYI!\n@DaveWalkerWHU\n@ExWHUemployee","updated_at":"2020-02-27T11:44:18.000Z","user":{"id":5491115,"username":null,"urls":{"profile":"https://audioboom.com/users/5491115","image":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/composite/%231c5fc7/150x150/avatars%2Fsmile-1.svg","profile_image":{"original":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/composite/%231c5fc7/150x150/avatars%2Fsmile-1.svg"}}},"link_style":"channel","channel":{"id":5019730,"title":"The West Ham Way Podcast","urls":{"detail":"https://audioboom.com/channels/5019730","logo_image":{"original":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/36150002"}}},"duration":32.4895,"mp3_filesize":575908,"uploaded_at":"2020-02-26T13:01:01.000Z","recorded_at":"2020-02-26T13:01:01.000+00:00","uploaded_at_ts":1582722061,"recorded_at_ts":1582722061,"can_comment":false,"can_embed":true,"category_id":283,"counts":{"comments":0,"likes":0,"plays":12},"urls":{"detail":"https://audioboom.com/posts/7515224-the-west-ham-way-podcast-we-re-back","high_mp3":"https://audioboom.com/posts/7515224-the-west-ham-way-podcast-we-re-back.mp3","image":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/36150892","post_image":{"original":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/36150892"},"wave_img":"https://images.theabcdn.com/i/w/8560839"},"image_attachment":36150892}]}}
```

At the moment im just trying to get the title and description from the json but i keep getting error message

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "audioclips", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "body", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"audioclips\", intValue: nil) (\"audioclips\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

here is my class for trying to parse the json

```
import UIKit

class PodcastViewController: UIViewController {


struct Root : Decodable {
    var body : Body
}

struct Body : Decodable {
    enum Codingkeys : String, CodingKey {
        case audioclips = "audio_clips"
    }

    var audioclips : [Clips]
}


struct Clips : Decodable{
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case description = "description"
    }
    var title : String
    var description : String
}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.audioboom.com/channels/5019730/audio_clips?api_version=1")!

 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        print("DATA EXISTS")
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        print(result)
    } catch {
      //  print("error while parsing:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        print(error)
    }
    }

    }.resume()
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

Any ideas why it says the audio clips key can not be found even though i am renaming it audio_clips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be detected and used, you coding keys must have the correct name, which is `CodingKeys` and not `Codingkeys` (uppercase 'K'):

```swift
struct Body : Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case audioclips = "audio_clips"
    }

    var audioclips : [Clips]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response, this can be your Codable struct. Try parsing using below struct.

```
// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let window, version, timestamp: Int
    let body: Body
}

// MARK: - Body
struct Body: Codable {
    let totals: Totals
    let audioClips: [AudioClip]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totals
        case audioClips = "audio_clips"
    }
}

// MARK: - AudioClip
struct AudioClip: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, audioClipDescription, updatedAt: String
    let user: User
    let linkStyle: String
    let channel: Channel
    let duration: Double
    let mp3Filesize: Int
    let uploadedAt, recordedAt: String
    let uploadedAtTs, recordedAtTs: Int
    let canComment, canEmbed: Bool
    let categoryID: Int
    let counts: Counts
    let urls: AudioClipUrls
    let imageAttachment: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title
        case audioClipDescription = "description"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case user
        case linkStyle = "link_style"
        case channel, duration
        case mp3Filesize = "mp3_filesize"
        case uploadedAt = "uploaded_at"
        case recordedAt = "recorded_at"
        case uploadedAtTs = "uploaded_at_ts"
        case recordedAtTs = "recorded_at_ts"
        case canComment = "can_comment"
        case canEmbed = "can_embed"
        case categoryID = "category_id"
        case counts, urls
        case imageAttachment = "image_attachment"
    }
}

// MARK: - Channel
struct Channel: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let urls: ChannelUrls
}

// MARK: - ChannelUrls
struct ChannelUrls: Codable {
    let detail: String
    let logoImage: Image

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case detail
        case logoImage = "logo_image"
    }
}

// MARK: - Image
struct Image: Codable {
    let original: String
}

// MARK: - Counts
struct Counts: Codable {
    let comments, likes, plays: Int
}

// MARK: - AudioClipUrls
struct AudioClipUrls: Codable {
    let detail: String
    let highMp3: String
    let image: String
    let postImage: Image
    let waveImg: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case detail
        case highMp3 = "high_mp3"
        case image
        case postImage = "post_image"
        case waveImg = "wave_img"
    }
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let username: String?
    let urls: UserUrls
}

// MARK: - UserUrls
struct UserUrls: Codable {
    let profile: String
    let image: String
    let profileImage: Image

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case profile, image
        case profileImage = "profile_image"
    }
}

// MARK: - Totals
struct Totals: Codable {
    let count, offset: Int
}
```

Comment: Is this some autogenerated code? Some part might be missing because `JSONNull` is undeclared...

Answer (score 1):

Just replace CodingKeys(uppercase 'K') instead of Codingkeys(lowercase 'K')

```
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case audioclips = "audio_clips"
}
```